# After extracting word, how to get remaining part?

Tags: java, android, regex, string, substring

Hi I have following string

```
String mytext="Hi I <am> John (Cena)";
```

Now what I am trying to make is, I want to display

'<**am**>' in bold and '**Cena**' in Blue color.

I am able to extract those words, but remaining part like 'Hi I John'

How can fetch that? I am not able to find a solution.

```
txttemps=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_temps);

List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?)\\)");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(mytext);

while (regexMatcher.find()) {//Finds Matching Pattern in String
    matchList.add(regexMatcher.group(1));//Fetching Group from String

}

for(String str:matchList) {
    System.out.println(str);

    colortext=str;
}

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\<(.*?)\\>");
Matcher m = p.matcher(mytext);
while(m.find())
{
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    //is your string. do what you want
    boldtext=m.group(1);

}
```

Comment: why you're not using substring method to extract required part

Comment: @khimji what is exact string? does it include '<' and '>' with am?

Comment: I would suggest to use the `split` method in the string class and use the `Span` API that Android introduces to slightly style text views. You could also use various `TextView` with proper constraints to have a similar behavior and the problem would reduce itself to find the words and use them in the proper `TextView`

Comment: @OnkarMusale String will be dynamic so we can not predict,

Comment: @Jabongg yes string will include lessthan and greaterthan symbols in string

Comment: @OnkarMusale 1 String could be : This is <my> world. 2 String could be : This is my <world>. Now I am splitting , but for second scenario it is giving Arrayoutofbounds pastebin.com/gxZZEFB7

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code

```
String mytext="Hi I <am> John (Cena)";
Pattern ptn = Pattern.compile("\\s+");
Matcher mtch = ptn.matcher(mytext);
mytext = mtch.replaceAll(",");
System.out.println("Array"+mytext.split(",")[0]);//[1][2] to get next elements in array
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SpannableStringBuilder str = new SpannableStringBuilder("Hi I am John Cena");
str.setSpan(new android.text.style.StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD),5,6, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
str.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 13, 16, 0); 
TextView tv=new TextView(context);
tv.setText(str);
```

Check [this](http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/android_textview_rich_text_spannablestring) link for more examples

Comment: What if string will come different? will this solution work?

Comment: Only if you'll dynamically find out the position of the strings you want customized.

Comment: 1 String could be : This is <my> world.
2 String could be : This is my <world>. 

Now I am splitting , but for second scenario it is giving Arrayoutofbounds

https://pastebin.com/gxZZEFB7

Comment: If all the time the world you want to bold or to change its color it's the same you could search for its position in your string.

Comment: For example : `String text = "This is my world" String match = "world" int position = text.indexOf(match);` You will see that position will be 8 and you know that 'world' has a length of 5 so code above becomes : `SpannableStringBuilder str = new SpannableStringBuilder("Hi I am John Cena");
str.setSpan(new android.text.style.StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD),position,position+5, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);`